# What happens if you don't set a machineKey in the web.configs on a web farm?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, owin

I have a single web application, on multiple machines in a farm.  If no machineKey is set, will each machine autogenerate the same key as the other and work correctly? (with regard to authentication cookie encryption, using OWIN)

Initially I would have thought no, but looking at the documentation it suggests the default setting is "AutoGenerate,IsolateApps", does the IsolateApps bit mean the automatically generated key will be the same for the same website on both machines?